# Export multiple MySQL results to CSV

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP script below.

It checks the *person* table for rows with the reference `PK001` & `PK002`.

When I run my script below, the output is the following:

```
ID,Reference,Email
1,PK001,mcg@gmail.com
```

I would prefer the output to be:

```
ID,Reference,Email
1,PK001,mcg@gmail.com
2,PK002,mcg@hotmail.com
```

~

**PHP**

```
$data = array("PK001","PK002");
$count = count($data);

foreach ($data as $value) {

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE reference = '$value'";
  $result = $con->query($sql);

  $csvheaders = ["ID","Reference","Email"];

  $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
  if ($fp && $result) {
      header('Content-Type: text/csv');
      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="export.csv"');
      header('Pragma: no-cache');
      header('Expires: 0');
      fputcsv($fp, $csvheaders);
      while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
          fputcsv($fp, array_values($row));
      }
      die();
  }

}

die();
```

Can someone please explain how I resolve this?

Comment: Why not use "IN" inside your query, and give it all the values in one go? It would be much more efficient. `SELECT * FROM person WHERE reference in("PK001", "PK002")` for example

Comment: Aaah - that's a very good call. I didn't know `IN` existed. Any ideas what I would change in my script to achieve that?  I did try removing the loop and using `$sql = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE reference IN ('$data')";` but no joy.

Comment: Won't your method overwrite the output on the second iteration of the loop?

Comment: You'd need to use `$ids = implode($data,",")` to produce a string variable - you can't stick an array directly into the query like that.

Comment: @droopsnoot When I do the above, I get the following error: `Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in generateCSV.php:19 Stack trace: #0 generateCSV.php(19): implode() #1 {main} thrown in generateCSV.php on line 19`

Comment: @droopsnoot I swapped it around and now my Query looks like: `SELECT * FROM person WHERE reference IN ('PK001,PK002')`. So close :-D

Comment: That's it, I put the parameters the wrong way round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `IN()` to compare to multiple values. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in for documentation on `IN()`.

Also you should use query parameters. Please do not interpolate values directly into SQL expressions. That's a good way to produce insecure, buggy code.

You need one separate parameter placeholder for each value in the array. You can't use a single parameter for a list of values.

Here's how I would write it:

```
$data = ["PK001","PK002"];

$placeholders = implode(",", array_fill(1, count($data), "?"));

$sql = "SELECT ID, reference, email FROM person WHERE reference IN ({$placeholders})";

$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param(str_repeat("s", count($data)), ...$data);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
```

Then proceed to loop over `$result` as you have done.

FYI, PDO is even easier, because you don't need to do any binding. Just pass the array to `execute()`:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

I would prefer to use PDO instead of mysqli in any PHP project.